# Average day of a month on minute precision

Tags: python, pandas

I have data with datetime index using minute resolution. I want to see what is the average 'profile' of one day in a month using minute resolution.

The dataset format is like this:

```
                               Power
2019-01-01 11:43:01+02:00   9.223261
2019-01-01 11:44:01+02:00  14.304057
2019-01-01 11:45:01+02:00  28.678970
2019-01-01 11:46:01+02:00  35.143512
2019-01-01 11:47:01+02:00  24.431278
...                              ...
2019-12-31 15:05:14+02:00  -0.075000
2019-12-31 15:06:14+02:00  -0.075000
2019-12-31 15:07:14+02:00  -0.075000
2019-12-31 15:08:14+02:00  -0.075000
2019-12-31 15:09:14+02:00  -0.075000
```

To plot the average day of a month power profile on hourly basis I did the following

```
plt.plot(df_jul.groupby(df_jul.index.hour)[['Power']].mean(), label=('July'))
```

where `df_jul` is a subset of the data above, including only data from July.

```
                              Power
2019-07-01 05:28:15+03:00  2.561204
2019-07-01 05:29:15+03:00  2.749837
2019-07-01 05:30:15+03:00  2.963823
2019-07-01 05:31:15+03:00  3.190177
2019-07-01 05:32:15+03:00  3.374277
...                             ...
2019-07-31 21:12:02+03:00  2.311575
2019-07-31 21:13:02+03:00  2.310808
2019-07-31 21:14:02+03:00  2.415743
2019-07-31 21:15:02+03:00  2.485820
2019-07-31 21:16:02+03:00  1.874091
```

The resulting figure is like this:

[image: Example plot]

So, what is the best method to get the same profile plot as in the figure above, but using minute resolution?

I tried to group it by minutes but that results in an average hour of the month. I also think I could just iterate through the dataframe and do the average calculations, but I feel like there is an easier way that I am missing.

Here is the correct result plot
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the `df_jul` subset? Do you only have 1 year of data? Also you already have a 1min resolution, what exactly do you think you could do?

Comment: @mozway I added example of the df_jul, but it has the same format as the main data. I only have one year of data, but I want to get a figure that shows an average power profile over each month.

Comment: So you want the profile for an average day of the month but with minute resolution? Or the profile for the month with minute resolution?

Comment: Profile for an average day of the month with minute resolution. The solution you gave below is not quite what I was looking for as it seems to give the latter one.

Comment: I updated it to add both options (if you can provide a larger dataset this would make nicer graphs to demonstrate the difference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with the desired frequency.

If you want to plot an average day of the month, you can transform all days to the end of month (with [`pd.offsets.MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html)), then `resample`:

```
(df_jul.set_axis(df_jul.index + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0))
       .resample('2min')['Power'].mean()
       .plot(marker='o')
)
```

Or with a variant of your original `groupby`:

```
df_jul.groupby(df_jul.index.floor('1min').time)['Power'].mean().plot()
```

[image]

If you want to plot the full month:

```
df_jul.resample('1min')['Power'].mean().plot(marker='o')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! The latter one is exactly what i wanted to do.

Comment: I updated the answer to show your final graph and I moved the desired answer to the top, so technically now the former is what you want ;)